# How to do a calculation by creating a new object in a method and using getters in fields in java?

Tags: java, object, methods, parameters, field

I need to take an object as a parameter for my method, i'll just make one up as an example.

For example my fields are:

```
   public class Calc
    {
    double a;
    double b;
    }
```

And in my method, I want to return the calculation of adding 'a' to 'b'

```
   Calc add (Calc adding)
     {
       Calc calc1 = new Calc1();
       Calc.a = adding.a;
       Calc.b = adding.b;
       return ????
    }
```

How would you actually do the calculation in the fields and how would you return it in the method?

Comment: You will never get anywhere trying to simply get the answer instead of trying it out yourself. Considering you've been trying to get an answer out of us for the passed 3 hours, go read the whole chapter on [classes and objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis are you actually following me or something... I have tried it out myself... That's why im asking for help.

Comment: Like a lot of people, I follow the java tag. I therefore see all the questions tagged with java. You have a serious misundertdanding of java syntax and classes. Stackoverflow is not well suited to cover such questions, even when you try to reformulate them a little better each time. Read your notes or a legit tutorial like the one I linked, try again, and then maybe come back after reading the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

`new` is a reserved keyword,you can not make the use of new as an object  meaning you can not name an object as `new`

Comment: I looked over it, it is now sorry @alfasin

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
public class Calc
{
    double a;
    double b;


    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(double a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public double getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(double b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Put this method in your class:

```
public void yourMethod()
{
    Calc calc1 = create your object;
    set values of 'a' and 'b';

    double sum = getSum(calc1);
}


public double getSum(Calc calc1)
{
    double aVal = calc1.getA();
    double bVal = calc1.getB();

    return aVal + bVal;
}
```

Comment: @RobL check the update..... at first, create a Calc type object and set the values of a and b...... methods are already supplied to set the values of variables of Calc object......

Answer (score 0):

`Calc.a` is actually "calling" a static member of class Calc, and like javaBeginner suggested `new` is a reserved word in Java - you can't use it as a parameter name. Try to compile your code before you post it on-line.

Answer (score 0):

please note

1. avoid setting value of a nd b inside add method
2. `Calc.b` is possible if b is static, in you can you need to access using instance of calc
3. if return type of add method is Calc, then calc should have some attribute to store result, instead i advice to change return type of add method to double

Answer (score 0):

it think you can simply use

```
Calc add (Calc adding)
 {
   return adding.a+adding.b;
 }
```

instead of using the `new` keyword

Answer (score 0):

In `add()` why you creating new object?